# How to add column filters to Excel worksheet using XLWINGS?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have almost finished my Python script for creating an Excel sheet. One of the last missing points is to add a filtering possibility to the top row of the sheet (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut in Excel), no filtering should be made, just added the filter. I know I can open the file and do it myself, but for the sake of automation it would be nice.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The shortest solution is to call the [`api`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html) property to activate the autofilter:

```
import xlwings as xw

path = r"test.xlsx"

wb = xw.Book(path)
ws = wb.sheets[0]

ws.used_range.api.AutoFilter(Field:=1)
```

But you can also use native xlwings functions (create a table object and then set its [show_autofilter](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.main.Table.show_autofilter) to `True`):

```
import xlwings as xw

path = r"test.xlsx"

wb = xw.Book(path)
ws = wb.sheets[0]

ws.tables.add(ws.used_range, name="a_table")
ws.tables["a_table"].show_autofilter = True
# This way adds formatting in addition to the filter.
```